# Ubuntu doesn't boot after Windows 7 installation?

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on my hard drive, then decided to install Windows 7 alongside on a 25 gb partition. I shrank my Ubuntu install by about 25 gb with a GParted Live USB. Ubuntu booted correctly after the shrink. I shut down and installed Windows 7 on the 25 gb partition. Now Windows 7 boots, and Ubuntu doesn't. Did I overwrite my MBR? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  EasyBCD to edit the Microsoft boot manager, too add ubuntu on to it. Then boot up Ubuntu and install Boot-Repair and reinstall grub and that should take care of it and set the default boot manager back to grub.

Boot-Rair

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
- update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (sudo boot-repair &)

From "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair"

Just post a comment if you just need me to go into more detail on this.

Comment: Thanks. I've used easybcd in the past, and I never thought of that. Thanks :D

Comment: Once you have booted into Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub` and then `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` where sdX is the drive, where you want to install grub.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that grub is installed. I'm just trying to recover my Ubuntu partition. I primarily use Ubuntu, I just need Windows for iTunes :)

Comment: The windows install has overwritten the MBR, `grub-install` writes back grub to the MBR.

Comment: The way that I answer is the way that I fixed for myself there maybe a more easier way that I don't know about since I don't use Windows Now.

Comment: How am I supposed to install grub if I can't boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: You need to create a live CD or a bootable USB drive, I like to use the rescue mode in the debian installer in such cases.

Comment: The easyBCD method worked great.

Comment: How do I rewrite my MBR so grub boots before easybcd?

Comment: See my comment above, Once you have booted into Ubuntu....